# Backbone click event not firing in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js, frontend

I have the following code and it works in every browser except Google Chrome.
I want every time I click on an option to alert me with the "You selected option (selected option number)" text.
I cannot make it work.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : "#eventPage",

    initialize : function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'changeNum');
        this.render();
    },

    render : function(){
        var a = [];
        var b = 0;

        a[b++] = '<div>';
        a[b++] = '  <select id="select">';
        a[b++] = '      <option class="sel" id="1">ONE</option>';
        a[b++] = '      <option class="sel" id="2">TWO</option>';
        a[b++] = '      <option class="sel" id="3">THREE</option>';
        a[b++] = '  </select>';
        a[b++] = '</div>';

        $(this.el).html(a.join(""));
    },

    events : {
        "click #select .sel":"changeNum"
    },

    changeNum : function(e){
        alert("You selected option "+$(e.currentTarget).attr("id"))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than listening for click on your `option` elements, you should listen for change on your `select` element:

```
events: {
    "change #select":"changeNum"
}
```

Then in your `changeNum` function you can get the selected option:

```
changeNum: function(e) {
    alert("You selected option "+$(e.currentTarget).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vt7t47br/